# Reporting on formatting VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a report that has a text box for a step listing. I'm needing to adjust the back color of it using VBA code based upon specific criteria based upon a query. I've set the code under the "On Format" of the details panel. If I call out one step it will change the color of step. If I call out multiple steps, it will only highlight the last box. For a test, I have a report that has 13 steps, but I want to have Steps 1 and 4 changed. Here's the code I've used:

```
If DCount("*", "qry_step_check1") = 1 And Reports![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].Value = 1 Then
    [Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngYellow
Else
    [Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngWhite
End If

If DCount("*", "qry_step_check4") = 1 And Reports![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].Value = 4 Then
        [Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngYellow
Else
        [Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngWhite
End If
```

In this case, only step 4 is changing. If I remove the listing for step 4, step 1 will highlight. At this point, I'm not sure if what I'm doing will work or if I'm just missing something simple. I have also tried using DLookups as well with the same results. I know that the code probably isn't the most efficient, but at this point, I'm just trying to get it to function and can worry about more efficient code later. This is quick screenshot of designview I'm working with. 
[image: Report Designview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much poking and prodding, I found a solution, might not be the cleanest, but it will work for what I need to do. Luckily it doesn't slow down the report too much.

```
Dim lngRed As Long, lngYellow As Long, lngWhite As Long
Dim i As Integer
lngRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
 lngYellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
 lngWhite = RGB(255, 255, 255)
 i = 1

Do Until i = 75

If Reports![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].Value = i Then
If DLookup("[Step_Int]", "[qry_step_check]", "[Step_Int] = " & i) = i Then
[Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngYellow
Else
[Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngWhite
End If
End If
i = i + 1
Loop
```

After a few days of using this code it was determined that on the large reports, it did slow it down too much. I ended up removing the code and setting conditional formatting on the 'Step' box and now it processes about 4 times faster. 
Here's expression used in the conditional formatting:

```
DLookUp("[Step_Int]","[qry_step_check1]","[Step_Int] = Reports!rpt_WI_Book!qry_select_step_filter_task.Report!Step.Value")=[Reports]![rpt_WI_Book]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].[Report]![Step].[Value] And DLookUp("[Task_ID]","[qry_step_check1]","[Task_ID] = Reports!rpt_WI_Book!Text474.Value")=[Reports]![rpt_WI_Book].[Report]![Text474].[Value]
```